# A simple function to format the correlation matrix of rcorr.adjust (RcmdrMisc)

Tags: r

here is the output of rcorr.adjust 
Pearson correlations:

```
    Eucgr.A00001.v2.0 Eucgr.A00003.v2.0 Eucgr.A00004.v2.0
Eucgr.A00001.v2.0            1.0000            0.1926            0.7389
Eucgr.A00003.v2.0            0.1926            1.0000           -0.0559
Eucgr.A00004.v2.0            0.7389           -0.0559            1.0000

 Number of observations: 12 

 Pairwise two-sided p-values:
                  Eucgr.A00001.v2.0 Eucgr.A00003.v2.0 Eucgr.A00004.v2.0
Eucgr.A00001.v2.0                   0.5487            0.0060           
Eucgr.A00003.v2.0 0.5487                              0.8631           
Eucgr.A00004.v2.0 0.0060            0.8631                             

 Adjusted p-values (Holm's method)
                  Eucgr.A00001.v2.0 Eucgr.A00003.v2.0 Eucgr.A00004.v2.0
Eucgr.A00001.v2.0                   1.0000            0.0181           
Eucgr.A00003.v2.0 1.0000                              1.0000           
Eucgr.A00004.v2.0 0.0181            1.0000
```

how I can convert it to a table contain rows and columns name and P and adjust P?

something like this:

```
row               column             cor   P-value  padj    
Eucgr.A00001.v2.0 Eucgr.A00003.v2.0 0.1926 0.5487 1.0000
```

Comment: You can extract the individual components. of the `list` output` i.e. `out$P` or `out$P.unadj` or `out$R`. It is not clear how you want the output to look like

Comment: I added the output format to the question, thanks